# Creating an object at runtime based on user's input

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to ask to the user whether they want to create an object or create a parameterized object (and taking the parameter as input).

The following sample program does what I want to however I believe that this is wrong since the pointer will be pointing to a memory which is no longer being reserved for my program (since the object obj goes out of scope).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass{
    int num;
    public:
        myClass()
        {
            num=0;
        }
        myClass(int parameter)
        {
            num=parameter;
        }
        ~myClass()
        {
            cout << num << endl; //for checking purposes
        }
};
int main()
{
    cout << "Use default(1) or parametrized(2) constructor: ";
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    myClass *ptr;

    if(choice==1)
    {
        myClass obj;
        ptr = &obj;
    }
    else
    {
        int para;
        cout<< "parameter: ";
        cin>>para; //input parameter
        myClass obj(para);
        ptr = &obj;
    }

    //use ptr-> from here on out
}
```

Comment: You have to use `new` to allocate it dynamically. And even better use a `std::unique_ptr<myClass>` instead of a `myClass*` raw pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I havent yet studied that unique ptr thing.

However, I'll try to do it with new.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ is right. If you haven't studied `std::unique_ptr`, go look it up, along with `std::observer_ptr`. Using raw pointers in new code is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay with objects with automatic storage duration ("stack allocated") then just factor object creation into it's own function:

```
myClass createIt(int choice) {
  if (choice == 1) return myClass();
  int parameter;
  cout << "parameter: ";
  cin >> parameter;
  return myClass(parameter);
}
```

Then, in `main`:

```
myClass object = createIt(choice);
```

Thanks to return value optimisation this (probably) won't lead to unnecessary copies.

Comment: In your code you are returning myClass() and myClass(parameter), would these return objects of type myClass?

what im trying to ask is, returning a constructor, returns an object?

Comment: The function returns an object of your class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your constructed objects are going out of scope - the pointer is then left pointing at an invalid memory location.

Use a smart pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class myClass{
    int num;
public:
    myClass()
    {
        num=0;
    }
    myClass(int parameter)
    {
        num=parameter;
    }
    ~myClass()
    {
        cout << num << endl; //for checking purposes
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Use default(1) or parametrized(2) constructor: ";
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    std::unique_ptr<myClass> ptr;

    if(choice==1)
    {
        ptr.reset(new myClass);
    }
    else
    {
        int para;
        cout<< "parameter: ";
        cin>>para; //input parameter
        ptr.reset(new myClass(para));
    }

    assert(ptr.get());
}
```